# Make an infinite animation jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make an infinite animation to a div.
I succeed to make an infinite moving div but it doesn't appear as a consistent animation. The div is moving then call the function again and move again, you see can when the animation stop and when it starts again.
This is the code I did:

```
this.movePipesHolder = function(){
    this.pos=this.pos-10;
    parent=this;
    $('#pipesHolder').animate({"left":this.pos},function(){
        parent.movePipesHolder();
    });
}
```

I hope I explained myself correctly.

Comment: It would be easier to provide a specific solution if you attach a JSFiddle of your code.

Comment: Your question is not clear, do you mean that the div should move continuously without slowing down and speeding up?

Comment: I want the div to move left flowless and to make it seems like it is a one animation that never stops and not as it is now.(move left stop move again, move left stop move again)

Comment: Strangely enough [this](http://tinyurl.com/p6dh6qs) (with a specified duration) looks a lot smoother.

Comment: what about using CSS animation ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to JQuery documentation [animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) takes the following arguments:

```
.animate( properties [, duration ] [, easing ] [, complete ] )
```

The default easing is set to `swing` which explains the animation behaviour you are experiencing, to make the animation move at a constant pace or speed you need to set easing to `linear`, to set the easing argument you also need to set the duration argument (the default duration value is 400):

```
this.movePipesHolder = function()
{
    this.pos -= 10;
    parent = this;
    $('#pipesHolder').animate ({left: this.pos}, 400, 'linear', function()
    {
        parent.movePipesHolder();
    });
}
```

Heres a working example on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arcm111/mcoko2h0/).

---

### Edit:

### The reason easing doesn't work without setting duration:

In JQuery documentation it's no where mentioned that duration has to be set for easing to work, so i examined the jquery source code to find out what's happining. This is the `animate` function in the JQuery plugin [v.2.1.4](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js) script:

```
animate: function (prop, speed, easing, callback)
{
    var empty = jQuery.isEmptyObject (prop),
        optall = jQuery.speed (speed, easing, callback),
        doAnimation = function()
        {
            // Operate on a copy of prop so per-property easing won't be lost
            var anim = Animation (this, jQuery.extend ({}, prop), optall);
            // Empty animations, or finishing resolves immediately
            if (empty || data_priv.get (this, "finish")) anim.stop (true);
        };
        ....
};
```

It creates `optall` object by passing `speed`, `easing` and `callback` arguments to `JQuery.speed` method, the following is the `JQuery.speed` function as declared in the script:

```
jQuery.speed = function (speed, easing, fn)
{
    var opt = speed && typeof speed === "object" ? jQuery.extend ({}, speed) :
    {
        complete: fn || !fn && easing || jQuery.isFunction (speed) && speed,
        duration: speed,
        easing: fn && easing || easing && !jQuery.isFunction (easing) && easing
    };

    opt.duration = jQuery.fx.off ? 0 : typeof opt.duration === "number" ? opt.duration :
        opt.duration in jQuery.fx.speeds ? jQuery.fx.speeds[opt.duration] : jQuery.fx.speeds._default;
    ......
}
```

It shows that:

1. The last argument provided is always set as the callback function (unless only two arguments are provided and the second is not a function or only one argument provided, in that case callback will be set to false).
2. The second argument is always set as the speed (this will be later on validated and changed to the default value if not valid).
3. Easing will be set to the third argument only if four arguments are provided, *or* three arguments are provided if the third argument is not a function.

So when providing only three arguments to `animate` the second argument is interpreted as `speed` rather than `easing` (unless the third argument is not a function then it'll be used for `easing`).

However after reading the source code i realized (it's also mentioned in the documentations) that you can pass the last three arguments in an `options` object `.animate (properties, options)` and in options you can add `duration`, `easing` or `complete` or combination of two or all of them, for example:

```
$('#pipesHolder').animate ({left: this.pos}, {'easing': 'linear', 'complete': function()
{
    parent.movePipesHolder();
}});
```

Comment: Where does it say adding a duration is a requirement for setting the easing type?

Comment: It doesn't say in the JQuery documentation however the easing won't work without setting the duration.

Comment: I came to that conclusion as well but a good answer would have an explanation. That's why I left it at a comment. To my knowledge, all arguments are supposed to be optional.

Comment: @Shikkediel Thanks for pointing that out, I edited my answer and explained the reason behind this behaviour.

Comment: Cudos for the research and effort.